# MariaDB Error while setting value '""'' to 'sql_mode'

Tags: mysql, mariadb, librenms

I have a LibreNMS (MariaDB 10.1.19 back-end) installation that has been happily ticking along for a couple of weeks, and today I logged in to see the dreaded

```
MySQL Error
No such file or directory
```

Digging around, I can see that the MariaDB/mysql process is no longer running.

When I start the process manually

```
sudo service mysql start
```

It waits for around 10 seconds before failing:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.  See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Digging through `journalctl --xe` I see the following error:

```
[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value '""'' to 'sql_mode'
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Any ideas where I should start looking next?  Google returns no matches on that error.

Comment: Has the `my.cnf` file been edited recently? It seems like some unicode left/right quote characters snuck in somewhere they aren't supposed to be, based on that error message.

Comment: Thank you - you were very close!  This system is built from an ansible playbook, and it looks like a recent edit in VIM has left some cut-and-paste junk behind (there is an 'i' in the middle of a string, presumably where an insert was done) which also happened to break the quoting.  Please switch your comment to an answer and I'll happily accept it.